# What is the C# equivalent of Java's getComponentType()?

Tags: java, c#, arrays, equivalent

I am translating from Java to C# and have code similar to:

`T[] @unchecked = (T[])Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), sampleSize`);

I know `getClass()` equals to `GetType()` in C# and `newInstance()` equals to `CreateInstance()`; but idk what's the C# equivalent of `getComponentType()`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getelementtype?view=net-5.0 ?

Comment: try this `T[] = (T[])Array.CreateInstance(array.GetType().GetElementType(), sampleSize);`

Comment: hehe C# is better (it has real generics not fake one like java - hehe you cant even get generic parameter in java at runtime without "TypeToken" solution) ... you can do `T[] = new T[size];`

Comment: [... so it's rather XY problem ...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/01IAtG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will work `Array.CreateInstance(array.GetType().GetElementType(), sampleSize);`